# CSS: how to define full width border on text layout?

Tags: html, css

I've defined these elements:

```
.price-btn {
    cursor: hand;
    font-size: 17px; 
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This style is used here:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="price-btn">My label</a></p>
```

The current result on my text layout is:

[image]

BUT I want full border width, like this:

[image]

How can I do that guys? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead,

Add to `price-btn` to `display:block` . Link tag(`<a>`) is **inline element**.

```
    display:block;
    color:#eda93c;
```

```css
.price-btn {
    cursor: hand;
    font-size: 17px; 
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
    border:1px solid #eda93c;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:block;
    color:#eda93c;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="price-btn">My label</a></p>
```

Comment: Perfect Rayees!

Answer (score 0):

'a' links behave like 'span's rather than 'div's by default.

Try adding

```
display:block;
```

to your css and also take it out of the surrounding 'p' tag